# При переходе на другую страницу исчезают свойства класса, передаваемые в скрипте js

Tags: php, javascript

В проекте написан код js, который при выбирании элемента из списка дает ему свойства css класса .selected. Когда выбираешь пункт из списка свойства класса .selected срабатывают, переходит по быбранному пункту и исчезают (выбирается на буквально на секунду). На jsfiddle этот же код работает!

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/tkwkpq8r/11/
```

Код из проекта:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".box h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        var text = $("span",this).text();
        $("span",this).text(text != "^" ? "^" : "v")
    });
    $(".leftSideBarElement").click(function(){
            $("li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
<div class="leftSideBar col-md-3 ">
<div class="box">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <h3 class="boldLetter leftSideBarCategory"><?php echo $child['name']; ?>
                <span class="expand">v</span>
            </h3>
            <ul class="leftSideBarSubcategoryList">
                <?php if(isset($child['children_lv3']) && count($child['children_lv3'])>0){ ?>
                <?php foreach ($child['children_lv3'] as $child_lv3) { ?>
                    <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
                        <a  href="<?php echo $child_lv3['href']; ?>" >
                            <li class="leftSideBarElement ">
                                <?php echo $child_lv3['name']; ?>
                            </li>
                         </a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

файл css:

```
.leftSideBar {
border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 0px; /*!!!!!*/
}

.leftSideBarLine {
border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}


.leftSideBarSubcategoryList {
padding: 0px;
margin:0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.leftSideBarElement {
font-size: 13px;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: inside;
padding: 10px;
color: #6C6C6C;
}

.leftSideBarCategory{
padding: 10px;
color: #6C6C6C;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
margin:0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.expand {
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
}
.boldLetter {
font-weight: 600;
}

.selected  {
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере на jsfiddle работает меню только по тому, что не происходит переходов по страницам, как следствие не перезагружается страница и стили не пропадают. В рабочем же варианте у вас клик по пункту меню открывает новую страницу, которая загружается сначала и соответственно состояние .selected в меню не сохраняется. Вам необходимо на момент загрузки страницы на уровне шаблона подставлять класс .selected или добавить JS логику которая после загрузки страницы по косвенными признакам сможет выбирать активный пункт меню.

Comment: DStrokov, спасибо Вам, хорошая мысль! Подскажите, пожалуйста, про js логику которую Вы имели ввиду

Comment: Например, вы можете взять все ссылки $('a') в меню или на всей странице, и сверить аттрибут href с текущим адресом на странице, у кого этот аттрибут совпадает, можно проставить класс .active или .selected. Вообще решение не очень красивое, но работать будет.